# Buffered reader not accessable by other methods

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

Sorry if this is obvious, I am inexperienced with Java. I have 2 methods, one that creates a BufferedReader, and one that processes it. However, the processing method can not access the BufferedReader, even though it is in a public method. Am I doing something wrong?

```
package textfiles;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class ReadFile {

    private String path;

    public ReadFile(String filePath) {
        path = filePath;
    }

    public void Open() throws IOException {
    FileReader read = new FileReader(path);
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(read);
    }

    public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException {



        int numberOfLines = readLines();
        String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];

        int i;

        for (i=0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
        textData[i] = buff.readLine();

        }

        buff.close();
        return textData;
    }

    int readLines() throws IOException {

        FileReader linedFile = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader  findLines = new BufferedReader(linedFile);

        String lines;
        int noLines = 0;

        while ((lines = findLines.readLine()) != null) {
            noLines++;
        }

        findLines.close();
        return noLines;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define BufferedReader at instance level just after declaring your path variable like

```
BufferedReader buff;
```

And in your method open, initialize it like

```
buff = new BufferedReader(read);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should return compile time error  as buff undefined variable. So declare it as instance variable and use it in any method directly.